# Sum cells with duplicate column headers in pandas during import - python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to do some basic dimensional reduction. I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
A B C A B B A C
1 1 2 2 1 3 1 1
1 2 3 0 0 1 1 2
0 2 1 3 0 1 2 2
```

I want to import as a pandas DF but without renaming the headers to A.1 A.2 etc. Instead I want to sum the duplicates and keep the columns names. Ideally my new DF should look like this:

```
A B C
4 5 3
2 3 5
5 3 3
```

Is it possible to do this easily or would you recommend a different way? I can also use bash, R, or anything that can do the trick with a file that is 1 million lines and 1000 columns.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try split the column names by `.` and `groupby` the first part:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  4  5  3
1  2  3  5
2  5  3  3
```

Comment: Another suggestion that might better fit the use case: `df.groupby(df.columns.str.replace(r'\.\d+', '', regex=True), axis=1).sum()`

Answer (score 2):

Just load the dataframe normally and group by the first letter of the column name, and sum the values:

```
df.groupby(lambda colname: colname[0], axis=1).sum()
```

which gives

```
   A  B  C
0  4  5  3
1  2  3  5
2  5  3  3
```

Comment: The actual data is 1000 columns and the names are variable length. Could I leave off [0] and just use colname?